# How to use laravel repository pattern searchable array?

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern, laravel-5.8

I am using laravel-repository pattern ,i have one api which is responsible for getting all users it's working fine ,if we are using that package by default search should support for that i set $fieldSearchable array in the repository class.

i hit an api like this **localhost.com/api/lists?search=foo**,it's not working can you please help me where did i mistake

`UserController.php`

```
public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
 public function getUsers(){
        $data = $this->repository->show();
        return response()->json(fractal($data, new UserTransformer()));
    }
```

`UserRepositoryInterface.php`

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface
{
    public function show();
}
```

`UserRepository.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use App\User as AppUser;
use App\UserSection;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/**
 * Class UserRepositoryEloquent.
 *
 * @package namespace App\Repositories;
 */
class UserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{

  protected $fieldSearchable = ['phone_number'];
    /**
     * Specify Model class name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function model()
    {
        return AppUser::class;
    }

    /**
     * Boot up the repository, pushing criteria
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->pushCriteria(app(RequestCriteria::class));
    }

  

    public function show(){
      return $this->model()::get();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe resolved by utilising pre-difined methods No need to write show() function logic because by default l5-Repository pattern contains some methods to get all the data `all()`or `paginate()`.in your controller write like this in getUsers()

```
$data = $this->repository->all();
or
$data = $this->repository->paginate('25');
```

all() is for fetch all the data from DB and paginate($limit) is fetch the data per page based on the limit.

if you are using any one of the above mentioned method then automatically search functionality will work